# 'if' statement causing 'syntax error near unexpected token `done'' in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm attempting to write a script that creates a new file within a loop every 5 iterations :

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
timestamp="$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))"
fileName="file"$timestamp".txt"
echo $fileName
while [ $counter -le 5 ]
do
        echo $counter
        ((counter++))
        timestamp="$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))"
        echo $counter
        if [ $counter == 5 ]
        then
            echo "Creating new file"
            fileName="file"$timestamp".txt"
            counter=1
        echo "${timestamp}" >> $fileName
        sleep 2s
        echo $counter
done
```

This script returns error :

```
file1561151901170.txt
ruunn.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
ruunn.sh: line 20: `done'
```

If I remove the `if` clause :

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
timestamp="$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))"
fileName="file"$timestamp".txt"
echo $fileName
while [ $counter -le 5 ]
do
        echo $counter
        ((counter++))
        timestamp="$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))"
        echo $counter
        echo "${timestamp}" >> $fileName
        sleep 2s
        echo $counter
done
```

The error is not thrown and the output is as expected :

```
file1561152065603.txt
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
```

So appears the issue is with the `if` clause ?

How to modify my script which allows the `if` clause to be included as part of file creation ?

Comment: This is a simple typo. The `if` statement is not properly terminated (by `fi`) before the `done` of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` is missing its closing `fi`.